# R - tidy a data set with rows of different lengths

Tags: r

This is an excerpt of a data set of Atlantic Ocean hurricanes from the U.S. National Hurricane Center:

```
AL011851,            UNNAMED,     14
18510625, 0000,  , HU, 28.0N,  94.8W
18510625, 0600,  , HU, 28.0N,  95.4W
18510625, 1200,  , HU, 28.0N,  96.0W
18510625, 1800,  , HU, 28.1N,  96.5W
18510625, 2100, L, HU, 28.2N,  96.8W
18510626, 0000,  , HU, 28.2N,  97.0W
18510626, 0600,  , TS, 28.3N,  97.6W
18510626, 1200,  , TS, 28.4N,  98.3W
18510626, 1800,  , TS, 28.6N,  98.9W
18510627, 0000,  , TS, 29.0N,  99.4W
18510627, 0600,  , TS, 29.5N,  99.8W
18510627, 1200,  , TS, 30.0N, 100.0W
18510627, 1800,  , TS, 30.5N, 100.1W
18510628, 0000,  , TS, 31.0N, 100.2W
AL021851,            UNNAMED,      1
18510705, 1200,  , HU, 22.2N,  97.6W
AL031851,            UNNAMED,      1
18510710, 1200,  , TS, 12.0N,  60.0W
```

The full data set has 21 columns and about 57,000 rows.

Each hurricane begins with a short row of three fields - the storm's ID, its name, and the number of long rows that follow that identify the track of the storm. In the excerpt here the first storm has 14 long rows and the second and third storms have one each. Each long row shows the position of the storm at the given time, and other information not shown here.

For each storm, I would like to take the ID and the name, and add them to each row of the track, to create this:

```
AL011851, UNNAMED, 8510625, 0000,  , HU, 28.0N,  94.8W
AL011851, UNNAMED, 8510625, 0600,  , HU, 28.0N,  95.4W
AL011851, UNNAMED, 8510625, 1200,  , HU, 28.0N,  96.0W
AL011851, UNNAMED, 8510625, 1800,  , HU, 28.1N,  96.5W
AL011851, UNNAMED, 8510625, 2100, L, HU, 28.2N,  96.8W
AL011851, UNNAMED, 8510626, 0000,  , HU, 28.2N,  97.0W
AL011851, UNNAMED, 8510626, 0600,  , TS, 28.3N,  97.6W
AL011851, UNNAMED, 8510626, 1200,  , TS, 28.4N,  98.3W
AL011851, UNNAMED, 8510626, 1800,  , TS, 28.6N,  98.9W
AL011851, UNNAMED, 8510627, 0000,  , TS, 29.0N,  99.4W
AL011851, UNNAMED, 8510627, 0600,  , TS, 29.5N,  99.8W
AL011851, UNNAMED, 8510627, 1200,  , TS, 30.0N, 100.0W
AL011851, UNNAMED, 8510627, 1800,  , TS, 30.5N, 100.1W
AL011851, UNNAMED, 8510628, 0000,  , TS, 31.0N, 100.2W

AL021851, UNNAMED, 8510705, 1200,  , HU, 22.2N,  97.6W

AL031851, UNNAMED, 8510710, 1200,  , TS, 12.0N,  60.0W
```

Is there a canonical vectorized way to do this? I have looked at the docs and several SO posts but I'm new to R and was unable to find an example I could adapt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one possible option to clean your data and convert it to a tidy data frame:

```r
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)
library(tidyr)

data.frame(
  text = readr::read_lines(text)
) |>
  mutate(id = cumsum(grepl("^AL", text))) |>
  split(~id) |>
  lapply(\(x) {
    first_row <- strsplit(x$text[[1]], split = ",")[[1]]
    x |>
      slice(-1) |>
      select(-id) |>
      tidyr::separate_wider_delim(text, delim = ",", names = paste0("x", 1:6)) |>
      mutate(
        id = first_row[[1]], name = first_row[[2]], n = first_row[[3]],
        across(everything(), trimws),
        .before = 1
      )
  }) |>
  bind_rows()
#> # A tibble: 16 × 9
#>    id       name    n     x1       x2    x3    x4    x5    x6    
#>    <chr>    <chr>   <chr> <chr>    <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> 
#>  1 AL011851 UNNAMED 14    18510625 0000  ""    HU    28.0N 94.8W 
#>  2 AL011851 UNNAMED 14    18510625 0600  ""    HU    28.0N 95.4W 
#>  3 AL011851 UNNAMED 14    18510625 1200  ""    HU    28.0N 96.0W 
#>  4 AL011851 UNNAMED 14    18510625 1800  ""    HU    28.1N 96.5W 
#>  5 AL011851 UNNAMED 14    18510625 2100  "L"   HU    28.2N 96.8W 
#>  6 AL011851 UNNAMED 14    18510626 0000  ""    HU    28.2N 97.0W 
#>  7 AL011851 UNNAMED 14    18510626 0600  ""    TS    28.3N 97.6W 
#>  8 AL011851 UNNAMED 14    18510626 1200  ""    TS    28.4N 98.3W 
#>  9 AL011851 UNNAMED 14    18510626 1800  ""    TS    28.6N 98.9W 
#> 10 AL011851 UNNAMED 14    18510627 0000  ""    TS    29.0N 99.4W 
#> 11 AL011851 UNNAMED 14    18510627 0600  ""    TS    29.5N 99.8W 
#> 12 AL011851 UNNAMED 14    18510627 1200  ""    TS    30.0N 100.0W
#> 13 AL011851 UNNAMED 14    18510627 1800  ""    TS    30.5N 100.1W
#> 14 AL011851 UNNAMED 14    18510628 0000  ""    TS    31.0N 100.2W
#> 15 AL021851 UNNAMED 1     18510705 1200  ""    HU    22.2N 97.6W 
#> 16 AL031851 UNNAMED 1     18510710 1200  ""    TS    12.0N 60.0W
```

**DATA**

```
text <-
  "AL011851,            UNNAMED,     14
18510625, 0000,  , HU, 28.0N,  94.8W
18510625, 0600,  , HU, 28.0N,  95.4W
18510625, 1200,  , HU, 28.0N,  96.0W
18510625, 1800,  , HU, 28.1N,  96.5W
18510625, 2100, L, HU, 28.2N,  96.8W
18510626, 0000,  , HU, 28.2N,  97.0W
18510626, 0600,  , TS, 28.3N,  97.6W
18510626, 1200,  , TS, 28.4N,  98.3W
18510626, 1800,  , TS, 28.6N,  98.9W
18510627, 0000,  , TS, 29.0N,  99.4W
18510627, 0600,  , TS, 29.5N,  99.8W
18510627, 1200,  , TS, 30.0N, 100.0W
18510627, 1800,  , TS, 30.5N, 100.1W
18510628, 0000,  , TS, 31.0N, 100.2W
AL021851,            UNNAMED,      1
18510705, 1200,  , HU, 22.2N,  97.6W
AL031851,            UNNAMED,      1
18510710, 1200,  , TS, 12.0N,  60.0W
"
```

Answer (score 2):

Another variation, but Stefan got there first (+1):

```r
library(tidyverse)

data <- read_lines(
"AL011851,            UNNAMED,     14
18510625, 0000,  , HU, 28.0N,  94.8W
18510625, 0600,  , HU, 28.0N,  95.4W
18510625, 1200,  , HU, 28.0N,  96.0W
18510625, 1800,  , HU, 28.1N,  96.5W
18510625, 2100, L, HU, 28.2N,  96.8W
18510626, 0000,  , HU, 28.2N,  97.0W
18510626, 0600,  , TS, 28.3N,  97.6W
18510626, 1200,  , TS, 28.4N,  98.3W
18510626, 1800,  , TS, 28.6N,  98.9W
18510627, 0000,  , TS, 29.0N,  99.4W
18510627, 0600,  , TS, 29.5N,  99.8W
18510627, 1200,  , TS, 30.0N, 100.0W
18510627, 1800,  , TS, 30.5N, 100.1W
18510628, 0000,  , TS, 31.0N, 100.2W
AL021851,            UNNAMED,      1
18510705, 1200,  , HU, 22.2N,  97.6W
AL031851,            UNNAMED,      1
18510710, 1200,  , TS, 12.0N,  60.0W"
) 

data |> 
  as_tibble() |> 
  mutate(type = if_else(str_ends(value, "W|E"), "track", "storm")) |> 
  separate_wider_delim(
    value, delim = ",", 
    names = c("id", "name"), 
    too_many = "drop", 
    cols_remove = FALSE
    ) |> 
  separate_wider_delim(
    value, delim = ",", 
    names = c("v1", "v2", "v3", "v4", "v5", "v6"), 
    too_many = "drop", 
    too_few = "align_start"
    ) |> 
  mutate(
    across(everything(), str_squish),
    across(c(id, name), \(x) if_else(type == "storm", x, NA))
  ) |> 
  fill(id, name) |> 
  filter(type == "track")
#> # A tibble: 16 × 9
#>    id       name    v1       v2    v3    v4    v5    v6     type 
#>    <chr>    <chr>   <chr>    <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr>
#>  1 AL011851 UNNAMED 18510625 0000  ""    HU    28.0N 94.8W  track
#>  2 AL011851 UNNAMED 18510625 0600  ""    HU    28.0N 95.4W  track
#>  3 AL011851 UNNAMED 18510625 1200  ""    HU    28.0N 96.0W  track
#>  4 AL011851 UNNAMED 18510625 1800  ""    HU    28.1N 96.5W  track
#>  5 AL011851 UNNAMED 18510625 2100  "L"   HU    28.2N 96.8W  track
#>  6 AL011851 UNNAMED 18510626 0000  ""    HU    28.2N 97.0W  track
#>  7 AL011851 UNNAMED 18510626 0600  ""    TS    28.3N 97.6W  track
#>  8 AL011851 UNNAMED 18510626 1200  ""    TS    28.4N 98.3W  track
#>  9 AL011851 UNNAMED 18510626 1800  ""    TS    28.6N 98.9W  track
#> 10 AL011851 UNNAMED 18510627 0000  ""    TS    29.0N 99.4W  track
#> 11 AL011851 UNNAMED 18510627 0600  ""    TS    29.5N 99.8W  track
#> 12 AL011851 UNNAMED 18510627 1200  ""    TS    30.0N 100.0W track
#> 13 AL011851 UNNAMED 18510627 1800  ""    TS    30.5N 100.1W track
#> 14 AL011851 UNNAMED 18510628 0000  ""    TS    31.0N 100.2W track
#> 15 AL021851 UNNAMED 18510705 1200  ""    HU    22.2N 97.6W  track
#> 16 AL031851 UNNAMED 18510710 1200  ""    TS    12.0N 60.0W  track
```

<sup>Created on 2024-03-16 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

@stefan and @Carl delivered `tibble` answers (up 2x), but It seems to me that @Pete asked for a text-only output, with blank lines between storms. If so, here's my take:

Input (as proposed by @stefan):

```
 text <- "
AL011851,            UNNAMED,     14
18510625, 0000,  , HU, 28.0N,  94.8W
18510625, 0600,  , HU, 28.0N,  95.4W
18510625, 1200,  , HU, 28.0N,  96.0W
18510625, 1800,  , HU, 28.1N,  96.5W
18510625, 2100, L, HU, 28.2N,  96.8W
18510626, 0000,  , HU, 28.2N,  97.0W
18510626, 0600,  , TS, 28.3N,  97.6W
18510626, 1200,  , TS, 28.4N,  98.3W
18510626, 1800,  , TS, 28.6N,  98.9W
18510627, 0000,  , TS, 29.0N,  99.4W
18510627, 0600,  , TS, 29.5N,  99.8W
18510627, 1200,  , TS, 30.0N, 100.0W
18510627, 1800,  , TS, 30.5N, 100.1W
18510628, 0000,  , TS, 31.0N, 100.2W
AL021851,            UNNAMED,      1
18510705, 1200,  , HU, 22.2N,  97.6W
AL031851,            UNNAMED,      1
18510710, 1200,  , TS, 12.0N,  60.0W
"
```

A pattern to identify the storm's id:

```
id_pattern = "^\\D.*\\d$"
```

The code:

```
    new_text <- read_lines(text) %>% 
      as_tibble_col("data") %>% 
      transmute(
        id = if_else(str_detect(data, id_pattern), data, NA_character_),
        id = str_squish(str_extract(id, ".*(?=,)")),
        data) %>% 
      fill(id, .direction = "down") %>% 
      filter(!str_detect(data, id_pattern), !is.na(id)) %>% 
      mutate(data = str_c(id, data, sep = ", ")) %>% 
      summarise(.by = id, data = str_flatten(data, "\n")) %$% 
      str_flatten(data, "\n\n")


# Discard the pattern
rm(id_pattern)
```

The text-only output:

```
> cat(new_text)
AL011851, UNNAMED, 18510625, 0000,  , HU, 28.0N,  94.8W
AL011851, UNNAMED, 18510625, 0600,  , HU, 28.0N,  95.4W
AL011851, UNNAMED, 18510625, 1200,  , HU, 28.0N,  96.0W
AL011851, UNNAMED, 18510625, 1800,  , HU, 28.1N,  96.5W
AL011851, UNNAMED, 18510625, 2100, L, HU, 28.2N,  96.8W
AL011851, UNNAMED, 18510626, 0000,  , HU, 28.2N,  97.0W
AL011851, UNNAMED, 18510626, 0600,  , TS, 28.3N,  97.6W
AL011851, UNNAMED, 18510626, 1200,  , TS, 28.4N,  98.3W
AL011851, UNNAMED, 18510626, 1800,  , TS, 28.6N,  98.9W
AL011851, UNNAMED, 18510627, 0000,  , TS, 29.0N,  99.4W
AL011851, UNNAMED, 18510627, 0600,  , TS, 29.5N,  99.8W
AL011851, UNNAMED, 18510627, 1200,  , TS, 30.0N, 100.0W
AL011851, UNNAMED, 18510627, 1800,  , TS, 30.5N, 100.1W
AL011851, UNNAMED, 18510628, 0000,  , TS, 31.0N, 100.2W

AL021851, UNNAMED, 18510705, 1200,  , HU, 22.2N,  97.6W

AL031851, UNNAMED, 18510710, 1200,  , TS, 12.0N,  60.0W
```